# Why do all *.localhost.yarf.nl domains resolve to `127.0.0.1`?

Tags: linux, dns

I discovered something funny today: all domains `*.localhost.yarf.nl` resolve to `127.0.0.1`.

- What is this?
- Where is this documented?
- I can not find references to it ...

Here some examples:

```
» dig aaa.localhost.yarf.nl

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> aaa.localhost.yarf.nl
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18392
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;aaa.localhost.yarf.nl.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
aaa.localhost.yarf.nl.  3244    IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 21 07:26:40 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 66
```

And:

```
» dig whatisthis.localhost.yarf.nl

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> whatisthis.localhost.yarf.nl
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27196
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;whatisthis.localhost.yarf.nl.  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
whatisthis.localhost.yarf.nl. 3600 IN   A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 55 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 21 07:26:52 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73
```

But:

```
» dig whatisthis.yarf.nl

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> whatisthis.yarf.nl
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 24959
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;whatisthis.yarf.nl.            IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
yarf.nl.                300     IN      SOA     ns091.auroradns.eu. admin.auroradns.eu. 2019011601 86400 7200 604800 300

;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 21 07:26:59 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

And:

```
» dig yarf.nl

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> yarf.nl
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13207
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;yarf.nl.                       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
yarf.nl.                3600    IN      A       5.157.81.33

;; Query time: 33 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 21 07:27:06 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

Comment: @grawity indeed, same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Why does it resolve to 127.0.0.1?**

It's a domain name whose owner has added an `A` (address) record with `127.0.0.1` as the value/destination. It's literally as simple as that.

```
NAME                   TTL    TYPE    VALUE
--------------------   ---    ----    ---------
*.localhost.yarf.nl.   1h     A       127.0.0.1
```

**Why does it work with *any* subdomain?**

It's a [wildcard record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record). If you add a subdomain named `*`, this is considered a "wildcard" and the server will respond with the same data for any name (unless overridden by more specific entries).